# Show that $x^2-\ln(x+1) = 1$ has at least one solution

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

How would one go about solving this?

My math teacher told me that i should find the solution for each of the joints(not what it's called in english?) so basically $x^2 = 1$ which has two solutions $x = 1$ and $x = -1$ then find the solution for $-\ln(x+1) = 1$ which would be $1/e-1$, but what comes after this?

Is there a formula for solving these or an equation or something?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no nice formula. Either, you need numerical methods or the lambert-w-function. The solutions are $x=-0.5186$ and $x=1.3639$.

Comment: Have you learned about the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: What methods can you use?  With $f(x)=x^2-\ln(x+1)-1$ we can remark that $f(0)=-1<0$  but $f(2)>0$, so there must be a solution between $0$ and $2$.  Is that acceptable?

Comment: @lulu It's acceptable once you have also stated (and checked), that the function is continuous :)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  Sure, but it isn't clear to me that the OP has access to these tools at all.  Mind you, I don't see any other way to attack the thing...

Comment: @lulu Since it's not possible to exhibit a solution, one has to prove that it exists, but I don't think it's possible to achieve this without relying, at least, on the continuity of the function (and then the IVT). These are relatively basic tools, though.

Comment: @lulu yeah i believe that would be acceptable as it proves there is atleast one soltuion, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define

$$f(x)=x^2-\log(x+1)-1\implies f(0)=-1<0\;,\;\;f(2)=4-\log3-1>0$$

and thus by the Intermediate Value Theorem for continuous functions, there exists $\;c\in(0,2)\;$ s.t. $\;f(c)=0\;$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = x^2 - ln(x+1) - 1$. We have

$$f(0) = -1 < 0$$ 
and
$$f(e-1) = (e-1)^2 - ln(e) - 1 = (e-1)^2 - 2 >0$$

By Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists at least one root in $[0, e-1]$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = x^2-\ln(x+1)$ Then $f(0)=0, f(100)=10000 -\ln 101 >1$ Now apply IVT

Answer (score 0):

On the interval $I=(-1,+\infty) $
$$ f(x)=x^2-1-\log(x+1) $$
is a convex function fulfilling
$$ \lim_{x\to -1^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty,\qquad f(1)<0 $$
hence $f(x)$ has exactly two distinct zeroes in $I$.
 By solving $f'(x)=0$, we also have that the absolute minimum of $f(x)$ over $I$ occurs at $x=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}$, hence we have exactly one root on the right of such a point and exactly one root on the left of such a point.